# Have table view content go above or below main area to achieve blur effect

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am currently developing an app which as a need for a box with some information above a table view. Unfortunately, I can not create the required behaviour with a standard UINavigationBar or a UIToolBar. I have instead created a UIEffectView with a blur background and placed this above my table view.

As you can see from this example in Apple's Stocks app, the table view content extends below the main visible area of the table view creating a nice blur effect.
[image: Example From Apple Stocks App]

My question is how can I recreate this whilst keeping the table view have a correct bottom and top area (if I just placed the blur view above the table view you would not be able to scroll to the bottom or top correctly, it would be obscured by the blur view).

Comment: can you so your design first. what you did.

Comment: yes, you can create.